# Prestashop backorders

Tags: prestashop

By default my store does not allow for backorders. I want some products to be allowed. So I go at the product and change it to allow it. So far so good.

My issue is when someone backorder that product. I want the system to automatically change its status to "ON BACKORDER" (which it's not doing) and, when I have the product on stock it change it again to payment accepted.

Is that a way of doing so? If so, how?

Thanks a lot guys

EDIT

What I would like to do is this:

- I want to star selling a product which will only be available 10 days from now, for instnace.
- So I add it with zero stock and choose "Allow backorder"
- When a client order this product and pay for it, I want their order's status to be set to BACKORDER and for then to receive an e-mail informing this

Answer (score 0):

So do you want that a customer has no ability to buy products that are on backorder? Because now it works how it should be: if product is out of stock=you can't buy it, if it's on backorder=you can buy it with so called negative store level. What you're trying to achieve is probably called Waiting list and is not a default Prestashop behaviour. There are [few paid extension on addons.prestashop.com](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/checkout/5224-pre-order-and-waiting-list.html) [for this](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/front-office-features-prestashop-modules/5014-waiting-list-pro.html)

Comment: Privet Sergei,

So, how does backordering works if not like a pre-ordering system? All I want is, when a product is backordered, for the status of a order with it to change to backorder and, when it's available, for it's status to change back to paid

Comment: If you want just to change text to notify customer that product is on backorder (i.e. display some text) than you need to follow this guide http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/prestashop-15/catalog-setup/allow-backorders

Comment: It's not that. I've added some more info to my post to make it more clear.